# How to truncate a string in a Text widget after every n characters

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I'm dealing with some big strings in a Row, and would like a string such as

```
0xaff0a761260a3c6a271738550f0d7669dc6de96b5629ed7398735c61b8c55555
```

to be displayed as

```
0xaff0a761260a3c6a27
1738550f0d7669dc6de9
6b5629ed7398735c61b8
c55555
```

if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full widget on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=a861e2e60bd266deda55653bf7da4f62&null_safety=true)

Use this method

```dart
  String sepText(String text, int n) {
    String result = '';

    int currentIndex = 0;

    while (currentIndex < text.length) {
      if (currentIndex % n == 0 && currentIndex != 0) result += '\n';
      result += text[currentIndex];
      currentIndex++;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

and use `Text(sepText(myString, n)`

Comment: This will degrade performance of your app so much that you shouldn't use this code, not even when building something for fun

Comment: @eja can you post your solution